# HTML table max-width property error

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, html-table

I am stuck at a website error and need help.
My website [**quantum-leap**](http://quantum-leap.net.in)

Opens perfectly well in Mozilla Firefox, IE.
But it does not open well in Chrome.
Apparently the problem is with `max-width` tag in the table.

I have tried almost every solution mentioned, like, wrapping table in `div`, `display=block`,etc.

But nothing seems to work. It will be great if someone can help me out with this.

Comment: what's your desired functionality ? and what's wrong with the current website running on Google-Chrome ? can you elaborate please?

Comment: can u give the css code of table

Comment: @NeophytePolyhistor, If you visit the site you can see that the whole layout is distorted, the width of the page is set to almost 8000px in google chrome, whereas it opens perfect in FF

Comment: @Amitsingh, I have used only inline css as of now, I will separate it out after the problem is solved.

Comment: Adding     overflow-x: hidden; to the body tag, solves the wide blank area issue, what else would you like to fix ?

Comment: please provide the inline css

Comment: @NeophytePolyhistor, Sorry but it didn't

Comment: @Amitsingh, there is no specific css applied to table, I tried all css tricks like i mentioned but nothing worked. You can rightclick and save the webpage, it will contain everything you need.

Comment: It does, I just did it again, click on inspect element, click on your body tag, and on the bottom right, below element.syle, add overflow-x:hidden!

Comment: @NeophytePolyhistor, it just hides the horizontal scroll bar, the layout remains same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove css attribute `white-space: no-wrap` from `<marque>` on the moving text.
However, the consequences is the moving text will no longer become one line.

Just out of curiosity, have you try to use [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) or [foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/).
Because, it has a lot to offer and I'm quite sure it will remove you from this kind of issue.

Comment: I surely use bootstrap, but this website is already done by some other developer and I do not have time enough to build this from scratch. So trying to repair it instead.

Comment: Thank you very much. It was a life saver. How did you debug to this? I mean there were many elements